# Is there a way to make every class in a project implement an interface (without doing a bulk find and replace)

Tags: c#, reflection, metaclass

Is there any way to do something like this: [In Groovy Is there a way to decorate every class to add tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691933/in-groovy-is-there-a-way-to-decorate-every-class-to-add-tracing) but in C#. Since C# doesn't support metaClass I'm stuck as to how to do it. If I could get this solution to work then I would then just iterate through every class using reflection and make it implement the interface.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: What's the purpose of adding that interface? Adding an interface doesn't automatically add tracing to your classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use dynamic proxies.

Why don't you take a look at Castle DynamicProxy? http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/

Or PostSharp, if you want to leverage AOP in a cleaner way:

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation

### UPDATE

The OP said in some comment:

> Ah, I'm actually using PostSharp to output what methods are called and
> when. What I'm tring to avoid having to do though is adding an
> attribute to every class in my code. So I figured I could just create
> an interface like this: [MyAttribute] public interface IDebug {} And
> make my classes implement this interface at runtime.

PostSharp supports assembly-level aspects: `[assembly:YourAspect]`. Later, in your aspect, you can check what method was invoked and to which object belongs to, and do the whole job depending on that.

Comment: Ah, I'm actually using PostSharp to output what methods are called and when. What I'm tring to avoid having to do though is adding an attribute to every class in my code. So I figured I could just create an interface like this:

[MyAttribute]
public interface IDebug {}

And make my classes implement this interface at runtime.

Comment: @JouNFU Did you know PostSharp supports assembly-level aspects? `[assembly: YourAspect]`