# Tracing in Groovy after start of every method/function

Tags: logging, groovy, annotations, trace, aspect

I got the same question as in
[In Groovy Is there a way to decorate every class to add tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691933/in-groovy-is-there-a-way-to-decorate-every-class-to-add-tracing)
but this answer is now several years old, so i wanted to know if there now is any better and more easy way to execute some code before, after or around the execution of methods. I would prefer something with annotations like

```
@TraceLog
class Foo {
   def bar() {
       println "in bar"
   }
}
```

or

```
class Foo { 
   @TraceLog
   def bar() {
       println "in bar"
   }
}
```

So that when i call bar(), some code (defined by TraceLog Aspect or similiar) is executed before "in bar" is printed.
Is that possible with groovy yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691933/in-groovy-is-there-a-way-to-decorate-every-class-to-add-tracing?lq=1

Comment: Or you could write an AST transform

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Local+AST+Transformations

Comment: Thanks! AST transformation was the keywords i was missing. So can i somehow mark comments as successfull answers?

Comment: @valenterry added as an answer (with a caveat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via an AST transformation, [as shown here](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#transforms-local)

Care should be taken with that example however as the `endMessage` is just added as the last statement in the method.  If the method has a return value, this is likely to be wrong...