# How to trace groovy shell scripts (e.g. bash uses set -x)

Tags: shell, groovy

I want to see every line executed in groovy script, thought that the `#!/usr/bin/groovy -d` switch turns this on, but doesn't. Bash has `set -x`, is there a way to turn on this behavior in groovy?

Comment: I doubt. It is compiled to bytecode, after all.

Comment: There is no direct way:  Here is _one_ way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691933/in-groovy-is-there-a-way-to-decorate-every-class-to-add-tracing?lq=1